# How to reset Winsock without reboot

Tags: networking, windows-service, windows-8

I often need to execute a Winsock reset, running
`netsh int ip reset`
and each time I have to restart the system.

Is there a way to avoid that?
Should I kill and restart *explorer.exe*?
Restart some specific Windows service?

Comment: Why do you need to do this regularly? That's not normal, I don't think I've had to do that more than a handful of times in the last decade. Perhaps you should try and solve the root cause instead?

Comment: "Restart the computer to complete this action." is pretty clear. And anyway, I can't think of any good reason to do this "often".

Comment: @MDMarra I'm also trying to figure it out and solve the problem. It's related to OpenVPN and often I need to reset to make it work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton in Windows is asked to restart as a solution to almost everything, while often some system modifications could work just restarting Explorer.exe or some specific services.
By the way I don't know if a winsock reset is into these cases or not. But I still wonder if a reboot is really needed or not...